# Getting the GUI of an app that went poof!

Tags: visual-studio

Today my Visual Studio disappeared. I can see devenv.exe in the 'Processes' tab in Task Manager but not in the Applications tab. I have unsaved changes. Is there a way to "revive" VS so changes can be saved?

Comment: I killed devenv.exe. When I ran VS again and opened the solution through recent projects, it didn't ask me whether I wanted to recover the files.
Oh well.. I didn't lose much because I save often. Just wanted to be prepared when it happens again. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it isn't a solution but VS if terminated unexpectedly (task manager end process) will usually recover open unsaved files when you re open it, Just make sure you open it directly and not by double clicking the sln file.

I would only try this as a last resort incase it doesn't recover the files.

HTH

Comment: I have autorecover now set at 1 minute intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I find that Windows GUI apps can still be running but not appear in the Taskbar or the Applications pane. First thing to check is whether you can Alt+Tab to it? Problem solved if so, but if not, try Process Explorer. Right-click on devenv and see if Window -> Bring to Front works. Since it lists all processes in a single hierarchical view it might be able to 'resurrect' VS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are toast.

But some versions of Visual Studio (and by that I mean the later releases) will save a current copy of open documents and you may find that it will ask if you want to recover them when you open it again.

Otherwise. No.  I think they have gone.